# Node Native AddOn in Electron Cross-Platform Use

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

If I use a Node native addon in an Electron app that will be used on Mac and Windows, do I need to do anything special to ensure that the correct flavor of the add-on (Mac or Windows) is used in each build?  I'm developing on Windows, but users will also be running on Mac.  I'll build the output with Electron-Builder.

Thanks.

Comment: `electron-builder` should handle recompiling any modules for each OS. If it doesn't work you may have to build your app using the os you're targeting.

Comment: @Teak: I was hoping that was the case.  I don't have a Mac machine available to test on ATM, so I'll just keep my fingers crossed.  Thanks.